# In Line Text Only Slide Toggle for Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1621/

*click on "Menu" to toggle the slide. Code is at the bottom of this post.

How can I make it so that "Menu" does NOT disappear, but rather the "Inner Menu" slides out to the left of it WITHOUT moving the position of "Menu" ("Menu" would be on the far right side of the screen and the "Inner Menu" would slide out to the left of "Menu" without moving the position of "Menu").

Thus clicking "Menu" leaves you with "Inner Menu◀Menu" & clicking again on "Menu" brings you back to just "Menu" being displayed.

Also, how can I make it so that clicking "Inner Menu" does NOT provoke it to slide away?

Thank you!

CSS

```
#categories {
    display: none;
    border : none;
    width: 100px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="cat_icon">Menu</div>
<div id="categories">
    <div CLASS="panel_title">Inner Menu◀</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#cat_icon,.panel_title').click(function () {
    if($('#cat_icon').is(':visible')){
    $('#cat_icon').fadeOut(function () {
        $('#categories').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
    });
    }
    else{
        $('#categories').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000, function(){ $('#cat_icon').fadeIn();});
    }
});
```

Comment: If you don't want it to disappear why are calling `fadeOut` on that element?

Comment: Because I'm stupid sometimes and forget to take stuff out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your JS to

```
$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
  $('#categories').toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
  }, 1000);
});
```

and change CSS to

```
#cat_icon {
  float: right;
}
#categories {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  border : none;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqnL6aqg/2/

Comment: This is cleaner js, but how does it answer his question? _"Menu" would be on the far right side of the screen and the "Inner Menu" would slide out to the left of "Menu" without moving the position of "Menu"_ ... _Also, how can I make it so that clicking "Inner Menu" does NOT provoke it to slide away?_

Comment: clicking "Inner Menu" doesn't make it slide away. I got that right. I updated the fiddle so now they are on the far right.

Comment: The CSS is a little finicky and doesn't play well with other elements on my page. I used the CSS from jeremyasnyder http://stackoverflow.com/a/32257730/5274135 Just an fyi for anyone else that needs this :) Thanks again!

Comment: Also adding "background-color: white;" in #cat_icon with different z-indexes for #cat_icon and #categories allowed the "Inner Menu" to not overlap the "Menu". Thanks to David for that! http://stackoverflow.com/a/32257723/5274135

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a snippet:

```js
$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
    $('#categories').toggle( 'slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#container
{
    float: right;
    /* to avoid the "Full page" div in the snippet iframe*/
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#cat_icon
{
    background-color: white;
}
#cat_icon, #categories
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
#categories {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id ="container">
    <div id="categories">
        <div CLASS="panel_title">Inner Menu◀</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cat_icon">Menu</div>
</div>
```

To avoid the overlap you can put a white background to the `#cat_icon` element.

Also, both `#cat_icon` and `#categories` elements don't get correctly
alineated due to the `◀`symbol. You can force the `line-height`to avoid it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers everything you are asking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/QDUQk/1627/

To ensure that clicking inner-menu doesn't dismiss it, you need to remove ".panel_title" from the .click() handler, like this:

```
$('#cat_icon').click(function () {
    if($('#cat_icon').is(':visible')){

        $('#categories').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);

    }
    else{
        $('#categories').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000, function(){ $('#cat_icon').fadeIn();});
    }
});
```

Other fixes included positioning elements... and providing a parent that they could be positioned relative to.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="cat_icon">Menu◀</div>
    <div id="categories">
        <div CLASS="panel_title">Inner Menu◀</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

and CSS like:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#cat_icon {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#categories {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50px;
    display: none;
    border : none;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS worked out best in terms of getting everything inline with the rest of the text on my website. Big thank you!